# How to get input value from <p-calendar> in primeNG?

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng

I have situation, when have to show selected value from input p-calendar. 
How to get this value from inputs and show underneath in the same format? 
I will add that it is impossible here to use angular2 date pipe, because I have array of dates not a single value.

My code: https://plnkr.co/edit/md3rRokf7FynTD5fz2gz?p=preview

```
<h3>Angular 4.2.6, PrimeNG 4.1.3, Calendar example</h3>
<div class="box-body">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <p-calendar maxDateCount="2" placeholder="Choose days" [(ngModel)]="dates" selectionMode="multiple" readonlyInput="true"></p-calendar>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <p-calendar placeholder="Choose range of date" [(ngModel)]="rangeDates" selectionMode="range" readonlyInput="true"></p-calendar>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            Your days:
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            Your range of date:
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply Bind the values there

```
<div class="col-md-12">
   Your days: {{dates}}
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-12">
   Your range of date: {{rangeDates}}
 </div>
```

## For changes in format

```
<div class="col-md-12">
   Your days: <span *ngFor='let date of dates'>{{date | date}}</span>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-12">
   Your range of date: <span *ngFor='let rangeDate of rangeDates'>{{rangeDate | date}}</span>
 </div>
```

if you are looking for something else let me know.

Comment: But in this case the format of date is wrong. I need the same format like in input.

Comment: check the Updated Method.

Answer (score 0):

To get the value from Input you can follow below steps,

- Declare reference variable "#myCalender" and "(click)" event in  tag as below snippet,
- Define "test()" function in .ts file

```js
  test(event, mc){
    console.log(mc.inputFieldValue)
  }
```

```html
<p-calendar #myCalender (click)="test($event, myCalender)" [(ngModel)]="value"  showButtonBar="true" showTime="showTime" hourFormat="24" [utc]="true"></p-calendar>
```